# Creating conditions and storing them in a list to index later

Tags: pandas, tuples

I have created a set of conditions with a pandas dataframe:

```
cat_A100 = df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(('A','B'))

sub_A101 = df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(tuple([f"A0{i}" for i in range(9)]))
sub_A102 = df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(tuple([f"A09"]))
sub_A103 = df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(tuple([f"A{i}" for i in range(15,20)])) |        df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(tuple([f"B90"]))
sub_A104 = df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(tuple([f"A{i}" for i in range(40,42)]))
sub_A105 = df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(tuple([f"B24"]))'
```

And used the conditions to create new variables:

```
df.loc[cat_A100, 'diagcat'] = 'A100: Certain infectious and parasitic diseases'
df.loc[cat_A100 & sub_A101, 'diagsub'] = 'A101: Intestinal infectious diseases except diarrhoea'
df.loc[cat_A100 & sub_A102, 'diagsub'] = 'A102: Diarrhoea and gastroenteritis of presumed infectious origin'
df.loc[cat_A100 & sub_A103, 'diagsub'] = 'A103: Tuberculosis'
df.loc[cat_A100 & sub_A104, 'diagsub'] = 'A104: Septicaemia'
df.loc[cat_A100 & sub_A105, 'diagsub'] = 'A105: HIV disease'
df.loc[cat_A100 & ~sub_A101 & ~sub_A102 & ~sub_A103 & ~sub_A104 & ~sub_A105, 'diagsub'] = 'A106: Other infectious and parasitic diseases''
```

Is there a way to make my code more concise? I am looking to create a tuple or list of the conditions, and then refer to them when I create the variables (second set of code)

Thanks!

Is this a potential way? Or is there a more concise way of formatting my code?

Any advice is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to store the subcategory conditions and their corresponding labels. Then, you can iterate over this dictionary to apply the conditions and assign the labels.

This approach reduces repetition and also makes it easier to update or extend your conditions in the future.

Here's how you can do it:

```py
# == Necessary imports =========================================================
import pandas as pd

# == Create example DataFrame ==================================================
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code': ['A01', 'A09', 'A10', 'A16', 'A41', 'B24', 'C01']})

# == Define Conditions ==========================================================
# Define the category condition
cat_A100 = df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(('A', 'B'))

# Dictionary for subcategories and their corresponding conditions
subcat_conditions = {
    ('A', 'B'): 'A106: Other infectious and parasitic diseases',
    tuple(f"A{i:02d}" for i in range(9)): 'A101: Intestinal infectious diseases except diarrhoea',
    ('A09',): 'A102: Diarrhoea and gastroenteritis of presumed infectious origin',
    tuple(f"A{i}" for i in range(15, 20)) + ('B90',): 'A103: Tuberculosis',
    tuple(f"A{i}" for i in range(40, 42)): 'A104: Septicaemia',
    ('B24',): 'A105: HIV disease',
}

# == Create 'diagcat' and 'diagsub' columns ====================================

# Apply the category and subcategory conditions
df.loc[cat_A100, 'diagcat'] = 'A100: Certain infectious and parasitic diseases'

for condition, label in subcat_conditions.items():
    df.loc[cat_A100 & df['Mr_Diag_Icd10_Code'].str.startswith(condition), 'diagsub'] = label
```

### Notes

The order that you define the conditions in the `subcat_conditions` dictionary matters. If you have overlapping conditions, you should define the less specific conditions first. For example, if the condition 'A106' precedes the other conditions, it should be defined first. Otherwise, it should be defined last.